# Algorithm for occurrence

Tags: php, algorithm

Can someone help me figuring out how to get if a current week is inside an occurrence .

I have the following vars : start_date , end_date , current_date week_occurrence .

and i have a function that return the # of occurrence

```
// will return the number of weeks between start - end
function get_weeks_count($start , $end) {
       return floor(abs(strtotime($start) - strtotime($end)) / 604800);    
    }
```

now i have to know if a current date is a valid date .

I have an entry with occurrence = every N weeks . How to know that N is valid .

**Less abstract :** If we are in December and the occurrence is every 3 weeks , start_date is 1st and end_date is 30 December)

It will return :

```
 TRUE  for 1st week

 FALSE for the second week

 FALSE for the third week

 TRUE  for the last week
```

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us the language you're using someone could find a library function to achieve this

Comment: @BlackBear Looks like PHP to me: Tagged

Comment: Given the Mth occurrence of an N week cycle, with start & end (assuming end is inclusive), then your date is valid if start + 7MN <= end.  Your date time functions should provide any additional support...

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to write an algorithm that allows you handle scheduling? i.e. Every 3 days, or every first Monday of each month?

Comment: yes Gavin but it's only for weeks , like every 2 weeks , every 3 weeks , every 7 weeks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem - this applies for an occurrence every $n weeks.

```
$n = $week_occurrence;
$occurrence = false;

// To begin, get the number of weeks between the start and current dates.
$weeks = get_weeks_count($start_date , $current_date); // Using the function you already have

// Now check if $weeks == 0
if ($weeks == 0) {
    $occurrence = true;

// If not, check if $weeks is divisible by $n without any remainder
} else if ($weeks % $n == 0) {
    $occurrence = true;
}
```

If `$occurrence` is still false then the current week does not fall within the the correct occurrence, if it's true then the week does fall within the scope.

Effectively all we're doing here is checking that the current number of weeks since the start date is either equal to zero (we're still in the first week) or is divisible by the ocurrence without a remainder.

I hope this helps.

P.S. I've only answered the specific question that you asked. However, if you would like to know more about how this premiss could be used for scheduling etc., then feel free to ask and I'll expand on my answer accordingly

Comment: i dont think this will work because when u test ($weeks % $n == 0) in most cases it will return zero let say you have a start date of 2012-11-01 and end date of 2013-12-08 , $weeks here is equal to ~57 so ... any 57 % n (where n<57) will return 0

Comment: @Commandos No, look at the code. Weeks is the number of weeks since the start date (i.e. the start date to the current date. and the modulus returns the remainder - not the number of times a number goe sinto another number. so 57 % 35 would return 22. If you have any other questions, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/dateinterval) should help you achieve this easily.

```
function get_occurences(DateTime $start, DateTime $end, DateInterval $period) {
    $weeks = array();
    $cursor = clone $start;
    $rate = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 week');
    do {
        /* We can check to see if it's within the occurrence period */
        if ($cursor == $start) {
            $isOccurrence = true;
            $start->add($period); // Move the start period up
        } else {
            $isOccurrence = false;
        }
        $weeks[$cursor->format('Y-m-d')] = $isOccurrence;
    } while($cursor->add($rate) < $end);
    return $weeks;
}

$period = DateInterval::createFromDateString('3 week');
$start = new DateTime('2012-12-01');
$end = new DateTime('2012-12-30');
/* From this array you can get both the number of occurrences as well as their respective dates*/
var_dump(get_occurences($start, $end, $period));

/** Output:

    array(5) {
      ["2012-12-01"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["2012-12-08"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["2012-12-15"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["2012-12-22"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["2012-12-29"]=>
      bool(false)
    }

*/
```